# New entity not persisting STATE_MANAGED

Tags: doctrine-orm

I'm trying to persist an entity and it's not working.  In my test setup, I'm successfully able to persist one of these entries.  In the actual code, though, It's not persisting.  So I deep dove into the code and I found that while persisting, in the persist that doesn't work, in `UnitOfWork.php`, the following line returns something different in each case:

`$entityState = $this->getEntityState($entity, self::STATE_NEW);`

`switch ($entityState) {`

Working returns: `case self::STATE_NEW:` or `2`

Not working returns: `case self::STATE_MANAGED:` or `1`

But the not-working code SHOULD be new.

Working:

```
public static function createAuthorizationCode(string $authorizationCodeHash, Client $client, DateTime $expires)
{
    $authorizationCode = new AuthorizationCode();
    $authorizationCode->setAuthorizationCodeHash($authorizationCodeHash);
    $authorizationCode->setClient($client);
    $authorizationCode->setExpires($expires);
    self::getEntityManager()->persist($authorizationCode);
    return $authorizationCode;
}
```

Not working:

```
public function setAuthorizationCode(AuthorizationCode $authorizationCode, string $authorizationCodeHash, Client $client, User $user, $redirectUri, DateTime $expires, $scope, $idToken)
{
    $authorizationCode->setAuthorizationCodeHash($authorizationCodeHash);
    $authorizationCode->setClient($client);
    $authorizationCode->setUser($user);
    $authorizationCode->setRedirectUri($redirectUri);
    $authorizationCode->setExpires($expires);
    if($scope)
        $authorizationCode->setScope($scope);
    if ($idToken)
        $authorizationCode->setIdToken($idToken);
    $this->em->persist($authorizationCode);
    $this->em->flush();
}
```

Not-working caller:

```
public function setAuthorizationCode($code, $client_id, $user_id, $redirect_uri, $expires, $scope = null, $id_token = null)
{
    try {
        $authorizationCode = $this->authorizationCodeRepository->getAuthorizationCode($code);
    } catch (AuthorizationCodeNotFoundException $e) {
        //this line is hit for sure and an empty object is being
        //passed into setAuthorizationCode
        $authorizationCode = new AuthorizationCode();
    }

    $oScope = $scope ? $this->scopeRepository->getScopeById($scope) : null;

    $this->authorizationCodeRepository->setAuthorizationCode(
        $authorizationCode,
        $code,
        $this->clientRepository->getClientById($client_id),
        $this->userRepository->getUserByUserName($user_id),
        $redirect_uri,
        self::timeStampToDateTime($expires),
        $oScope,
        $id_token);

    return true;
}
```

Model:

```
<?php
namespace PIAuth\Entity\AccessToken;

use PIAuth\Entity\Client\Client;
use PIAuth\Entity\Scope\Scope;
use PIAuth\Entity\User\User;
use DateTime;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class AccessToken
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->deleted = false;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", unique=true, length=40, nullable=false)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $accessTokenHash;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=80, nullable=true)
     * @var string
     */
    protected $idToken;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean")
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $deleted;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PIAuth\Entity\Client\Client")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="clientId")
     * @var Client
     */
    protected $client;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PIAuth\Entity\User\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="userName")
     * @var User
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @var DateTime
     */
    protected $expires;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PIAuth\Entity\Scope\Scope")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="scope")
     * @var Scope
     */
    protected $scope;

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getAccessTokenHash(): string
    {
        return $this->accessTokenHash;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $accessTokenHash
     */
    public function setAccessTokenHash(string $accessTokenHash)
    {
        $this->accessTokenHash = $accessTokenHash;
    }

    /**
     * @return Client
     */
    public function getClient()
    {
        return $this->client;
    }

    /**
     * @param Client $client
     */
    public function setClient(Client $client)
    {
        $this->client = $client;
    }

    /**
     * @return User
     */
    public function getUser()
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    /**
     * @param User $user
     */
    public function setUser(User $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    /**
     * @return DateTime
     */
    public function getExpires(): DateTime
    {
        return $this->expires;
    }

    /**
     * @param DateTime $expires
     */
    public function setExpires(DateTime $expires)
    {
        $this->expires = $expires;
    }

    /**
     * @return Scope
     */
    public function getScope()
    {
        return $this->scope;
    }

    /**
     * @param Scope $scope
     */
    public function setScope(Scope $scope)
    {
        $this->scope = $scope;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getIdToken()
    {
        return $this->idToken;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $idToken
     */
    public function setIdToken($idToken)
    {
        $this->idToken = $idToken;
    }

    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function isDeleted(): bool
    {
        return $this->deleted;
    }

    /**
     * @param bool $deleted
     */
    public function setDeleted(bool $deleted)
    {
        $this->deleted = $deleted;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `AuthorizationCodeNotFoundException` is not catched. Are you in the same namespace or do you have any `use` for it?

Try inserting a `die(1)` in the catch block to see if it gets executed.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the exception.  I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0):

Wow.  This one is a head-scratcher.  The problem is how Doctrine marks entities as persisted.
Using the `spl-object-hash` http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-object-hash.php

The problem is destroying the database and recreating it in the same process which needs to be done for each test.  You'll see that one of the notes in the doc says,

> Note that the contents (properties) of the object are NOT hashed by the function, merely its internal handle and handler table pointer. This is sufficient to guarantee that any two objects simultaneously co-residing in memory will have different hashes. Uniqueness is not guaranteed between objects that did not reside in memory simultaneously, for example:
>
> var_dump(spl_object_hash(new stdClass()), spl_object_hash(new stdClass()));
>
> Running this alone will usually generate the same hashes, since PHP reuses the internal handle for the first stdClass after it has been dereferenced and destroyed when it creates the second stdClass.

And that is percicely the reason.  Doctine thinks my new entity is an entity that has already been hashed.

The solution to this was to also create a new `EntityManager`.  Hope this helps some poor soul.  Don't be afraid to deep-dive the code.

Comment: Without creating a new entity manager, you could simply call $em->clear() right after having destroyed your dB. See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#entities-and-the-identity-map . This also let you save some memory because all previously managed entities become detached and can be garbage collected.